# How to remove the dummy contacts from the default contact DB

Tags: civievent

How can we remove the dummy contacts from the default contact database?

Comment: it will help you to get answers if you add more info to your question: what do you mean with dummy contacts, what version of CiviCRM are you referring to, what CMS are you using, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have loaded the sample data and you want to get rid of those? If that is the case, best advice is re-install WITHOUT loading the sample data. If you have loaded the sample data, you do not only have contacts but also cases, contributions, pledges, activities, events etc. and some configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, assuming you have data already in your contact DB.

- Install a fresh DB with test data, or visit the CiviCRM demo site
- Use CiviCRM's export to export the (test) contacts to CSV with essential contact details
- Import this CSV into your CiviCRM site, choosing "Fill" to avoid overwriting any "real" contacts, and making these contacts members of a "To remove" group
- View the members of this To Remove group
- Select all contacts displayed, review and deselect any who should not be deleted
- Use the actions to Delete contacts

Answer (score 1):

If you do just want to get rid of those example contacts then the problem of deleting Contacts is that any that have Contributions will need those deleting first or you will get this "This contact(s) can not be permanently deleted because the contact record is linked to one or more live financial transactions. Deleting this contact would result in the loss of financial data." when you try and Permanently Delete.

Your test records should all have an ID below 'x'. You should be able to use Search Builder or Adv Search and find all those contacts either by Internal ID, or 'date created' (under changelog in Adv Search) and get them all in to a Group eg D.

Then in Adv Search say 'find all contacts in Group D', set Adv Search to 'show results as Contributions' then delete those contributions, then delete the Contacts.